# Can't find app on google play store, even after two weeks, but its there

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded a new version of my app of the google play store, now I can't find it there using any of the following methods:
Searching for its name.
Searching by its package.
Seaching on my pc and on my device.
The apps by the same developer its doesn't show in that list.
On the console it says published, and even can click the link to view in google store, and I do see it there. Buts its not in any of the searchs above?
Why is this?
Thanks

UPDATE - I don't have an answer to this. I have the link for the app on the store, but any search doesn't work, not on a device and not on a pc. I have waited over 2 weeks, and its still not there. Also, its not showing with the other apps I made, from the same developer. Thanks!

Comment: You should wait several hours for the store to update.

Comment: Still not updated, after two weeks

Comment: Can you post the link?

Comment: Check my answer, I just figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that the app was only distributed to one country. Now I selected all countries, its shows up in the search.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is that the update is still in progress. An app listing can sometimes take a few hours to work it's way through the submission process and out to all of the Google servers.

Also, if you changed any of the device requirements (which may be implied by the permissions requested), it could exclude your device(s) from seeing the app. The easiest way to check for this is to do the Google Play search via a web browser. If any/all your devices are excluded, the listing  will say so near the top of the page.

Comment: Waited two weeks and still not showing. Also doesn't show in web browser search.

Comment: I see your self-posted answer about your app being country-limited and that would explain your particular issue, but to clarify for others, I'll mention this: I've never seen it take more than a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I think in my case I didn't choose option "Contains ads: Yes, it has ads" in my play console afrer updating app with added ads.

To change that in Play Console go to your app; then "Store presence"->"Pricing & distribution" and choose "Yes, it has ads" in "Contains ads" section. In my case it helped immidiately, now I can find app by some keywords.